# Share Common AppResource Strings With Android Accessibility Service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I share translations for my iOS and Android apps through a common PCL that has `AppResources.resx` files. I access my resource strings in C# code like `AppResources.MyString`.

This has worked well up until now, when I have introduced an accessibility service into my android app.

With the accessibility service, I need to provide a description. The only documentation I can find always shows this description being set in the `accessibilityservice.xml` file such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description" />
```

Which is bound to the service like:

```
[Service(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE", Label = "MyApp")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
[MetaData("android.accessibilityservice", Resource = "@xml/accessibilityservice")]
public class AutofillService : AccessibilityService
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously I cannot access `AppResources.MyAccessibilityDescString` from the `accessibilityservice.xml` file, so how do I provide my translatable `AppResources` string to the accessibility service description?

I would hate to have to manage other android specific strings in the android project only instead of having a common place my translators can set all strings for the app (`AppResources.resx`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the `AppResources.resx` content in xml file. And unfortunately the `Description` property of `AccessibilityServiceInfo` is read only. So you can not set the value by `SetServiceInfo` method.

The only option I can think of is to add the description string in the `String.xml`file.